# Create a safe reference object technique used in Underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

When I go through the code in `Underscore` : http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html

I came across

```
var _ = function(obj) {
  if (obj instanceof _) return obj;
  if (!(this instanceof _)) return new _(obj);
  this._wrapped = obj;
};
```

with comment

> Create a safe reference to the Underscore object for use below.

I don't really understand the purpose. Instead of having

```
(function() {
    var _ = function(obj) {
        if (obj instanceof _) return obj;
        if (!(this instanceof _)) return new _(obj);
        this._wrapped = obj;
    };

    _.VERSION = '1.7.0';
})();
```

Why can't we just simply have

```
(function() {
    var _ = {};

    _.VERSION = '1.7.0';
})();
```

May I know why idea behind technique used by `Underscore` project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This force the creation of object using the constructor pattern: `_()` would be equivalent to `new _()`

then if you want to extend the behavior of all instance ie objects created with `_(obj)` (or `new _(obj)` with a limited memory usage you can extend the prototype of the constructor.

```
function Ctor(){}

Ctor.prototype.someFunction=function(){};

var instance1=new Ctor();
var instance2=new Ctor();
```

would be somehow equivalent to

```
function factory(){
   var obj={};
   obj.someFunction=function(){}
   return obj;
}

var instance1=factory();
var instance2=factory();
```

but the second version will use more memory as it will add the function to every instance rather to the single common prototype